# Python 3.9 Tests in separate directory - Module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on my first python project, and I would like to structure the folders correctly.
What I have so far is :

```
HomeDir/MyProject/
        ConfigHandler.py
HomeDir/Tests/
        ConfigHanderTests.py
```

In the ConfigHanderTests.py I am importing a module defined in ConfigHandler.py called ConfigHandler :

```
from ConfigHandler import ConfigHandler
```

But when I run the tests using :

```
python -m unittest ConfigHandlerTests
```

I get the following error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigHandler'
```

I have read that I need an **init**.py in the test folder? But other posts mention that is no longer required.
If I just have all the python files and test files in one directory, it works fine. But splitting out into folders doesn't work. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: tests folder should be inside your main project. move `Tests/ConfigHanderTests.py` inside `MyProject/` and change your imports accordingly.

Comment: That doesn't really feel like "the correct structure". Create a project folder, and nest everything that's relevant to that project in that project folder (venv, tests, docs, etc).

Comment: `from config_handler.simple import Simple` and `from config_handler.advanced import Advanced`

Comment: So should I just have one folder, and everything lives within that? I wanted to separate the tests into their own folder...